# SCCM query: How to get Latest user-logon registration (if any) and display PC, IP, User, logontimestamp

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I'm trying to create a SQL 2005 query to retrieve and combine records from 3 SCCM Data Views.
The first view contains records of valid PC's; the second contains logon-information containing: PC-id, username, timestamp, etc; the third contains PC-id, IP-address.

The 1stview only contains a single, nique record per PC; the 2nd view can contain multiple records per PC: one for each time a user logs on to a computer; the 3rd can contain multiple records per PC: one for each IP that has been registered in the database.

so it's like:

```
view1 (v_R_System_Valid) fields (among others)
ResourceID, NetBIOS

view2 (v_GS_SYSTEM_CONSOLE_USER) fields (among others)
id,ResourceID,SystemConsoleUser0,LastConsoleUse0 

view3 (v_RA_System_IPAddresses)  fields (among others)
ResourceID,IP_Addresses0
```

I WANT the query to present me a list of all PC's in the first view, and also display (is available) the IP address; the LATEST time a logon occurred and by WHOM.

The query I built sofar returns each PC, but includes EACH user that logged on to that PC and when, not the latest only. I hope anyone can help me figure this out. I'm not an experienced SQL scripter and constructed the code below using info from the Net.

My query:

```
Select 
SV.Netbios_Name0 AS [NetBIOS Name],
SCU.SystemConsoleUser0 AS [User Name],
CAST(ISNULL(SCU.theLastTime, 0) AS datetime ) AS [Last Console Use]

from v_R_System_Valid SV
 Left Join (Select ResourceID, SystemConsoleUser0,
                Max(LastConsoleUse0) as theLastTime 
            from v_GS_SYSTEM_CONSOLE_USER 
            group by ResourceID, SystemConsoleUser0) 
     AS SCU on SCU.ResourceID = SV.ResourceID

where (SV.Netbios_Name0 not like 'ENC-%')
and (SV.Netbios_Name0 not like 'NL%')

order by SV.Netbios_Name0
```

Thanks in advance,
Eric

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT SV.Netbios_Name0 AS [NetBIOS Name]      
       , latest_user.SystemConsoleUser0 as [User Name]
       , CAST(ISNULL(SCU.theLastTime, 0) AS datetime ) AS [Last Console Use]
       , IP.IP_Addresses0
from   v_R_System_Valid SV 
       left outer join
                 (Select  ResourceID
                          ,Max(LastConsoleUse0) as theLastTime 
                 from     v_GS_SYSTEM_CONSOLE_USER 
                 group by ResourceID
                          ,SystemConsoleUser0) AS SCU 
       on SCU.ResourceID = SV.ResourceID

       left outer join v_GS_SYSTEM_CONSOLE_USER as latest_user
       on latest_user.LastConsoleUse0 = SCU.theLastTime
   and
       latest_user.ResourceID = SCU.ResourceID
       left outer join v_RA_System_IPAddresses as IP
       on IP.ResourceID = SV.ResourceID
where  (SV.Netbios_Name0 not like 'ENC-%') 
    and 
       (SV.Netbios_Name0 not like 'NL%')
order by SV.Netbios_Name0
```

Comment: Hi Adam. Thanks a lot for this nice way to combine multiple joins. Didn't know this. You made one typo 'latestuser.resourceID' instead of 'latest_user.resourceID', and I removed the SystemConsoleUser0 from the Group by clause to get only the latest user-logon registration.
Also added another AND in the join with v_RA_System_IPAddresses to get only IP's starting with '10.%'. Couldn't have done it without your help. Thanks.

Comment: Nice work evegter!  Yep, I had two big typos.  Good on ya for sniffing those out, and making the thing work for your purposes.

Answer (score 0):

With the help from Adam I came to this resulting query:

```
select SV.Netbios_Name0 AS [NetBIOS Name]
   , latest_user.SystemConsoleUser0 as [User Name]
   , CAST(ISNULL(SCU.theLastTime, 0) AS datetime ) AS [Last Console Use]
   , IP.IP_Addresses0
from   v_R_System_Valid SV
    left outer join
        (Select ResourceID
             ,Max(LastConsoleUse0) as theLastTime
        from v_GS_SYSTEM_CONSOLE_USER
        group by ResourceID) AS SCU
        on SCU.ResourceID = SV.ResourceID
    left outer join v_GS_SYSTEM_CONSOLE_USER as latest_user
        on latest_user.LastConsoleUse0 = SCU.theLastTime
             and
           latest_user.ResourceID = SCU.ResourceID
    left outer join v_RA_System_IPAddresses as IP
        on IP.ResourceID = SV.ResourceID where (SV.Netbios_Name0 not like 'ENC-%')
            and
            (SV.Netbios_Name0 not like 'NL%')
            and
            (IP.IP_Addresses0 like '10.%')
        order by SV.Netbios_Name0
```